# FullScreenForm validation every input filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I'm trying to make this form working on my website : http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenForm/

My goal is to validate every input when submitted and show the error when there is one.

For this I already did an ajax call to every validation to check if there is an error. (the backend side is ready for this)

But I meet 2 problems with this :
it's async call so it doesn't go in the flow and it validates before the ajax call is finished.

Secondly, When I have the error on the data and try to launch the this._showError(error) it says that it's not a function.

How can I reach the this._showError within a function ?

Here is the code :

```
    FForm.prototype._validade = function() {

    var fld = this.fields[this.current],
        input = fld.querySelector( 'input' ) || fld.querySelector( 'textarea' ) || fld.querySelector( 'select' ),
        error,
        data = {'form_class': this.form_class, 'field': fld.querySelector('input').name, 'data': fld.querySelector('input').value};
        $(input).prop('disabled', true)
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/core/validate_field',
          data: data,
          dataType:'json',
        }).done(function(data){
            if (data['status'] === 'error') {
                error = data['message'];
                this._showError( error );
                return false;
            }
            $(input).prop('disabled', false);
        }

        )
    if( error != undefined ) {
        this._showError( error );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// TODO
FForm.prototype._showError = function( message ) {

    this.msgError.innerHTML = message;
    this._showCtrl( this.msgError );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code who answered the question I did

```
    FForm.prototype._validade = function() {
    var fld = this.fields[this.current],
        input = fld.querySelector( 'input' ) || fld.querySelector( 'textarea' ) || fld.querySelector( 'select' ),
        error,
        data = {'form_class': this.form_class, 'field': fld.querySelector('input').name, 'data': fld.querySelector('input').value},
        $this = this;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/core/validate_field',
          data: data,
          dataType:'json',
        }).done(function(data){
            if (data['status'] === 'error') {
                error = data['message'];
                $this._showError( error );
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        )

}
```

If you have any suggestions, it's welcome :)